# Python: How to print the output of a for loop?

Tags: python

I have this code

```
x = random.randint(0,1)
y = 100
for x in range(y):
```

What's now? How do I print the output? I tried printing x but it didn't work.

Comment: What output do you want.

Comment: Are you want to print 100 random number.

Comment: What do you mean "printing x didnt work"?

Comment: What did you try exactly and what do you mean by "didn't work"? See [ask].

Comment: @Ann Zen - The printing tag isn't for using python's print function, but printing on paper. (and the question is about printing an output, it doesn't mention random being the issue)

Comment: You have asked a question about the very basics of Python. I'd like to remind you that Stack Overflow can not replace actually learning a language.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = random.randint(0,1) 
y = 100 
for x in range(y):
    print(x)
```

I'm not sure if it is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? To print `y` random integer between 0 and 1.

```
y = 100
for i in range(y):
    x = random.randint(0,1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thx! Is there a way that I can print x into a single line or string, because this way python prints just one number in a line?

Answer (score 0):

@DragonPeti *"Thx! Is there a way that I can print x into a single line or string because this way python prints just one number in a line?"*

```py
y = 100 
for a in range(y):
    print(random.randint(0,1),end='')
```

OUTPUT

```py
1100000000001101010100100011010100010000000101000111100011101101001011000100001100111000011111001000

# OR Changing end='' to end=' '

1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get a random number between `0` and `1` for each iteration of the `for` loop is because

1. You have overwritten the value of `x` at `for x in`, and
2. You did not redefine `x` to be a random number in the loop, so even if you were to remove the part that overwrites `x`, it will remain the same number throughout the loop.

This is what you want:

```
y = 100
for _ in range(y):
    x = random.randint(0,1)
    print(x)
```

With the above, you *can* replace the `_` with `x` and it will not be affected, but it's better practice to use `_` when iterating though an iterable with ever using the values within the iterable.